# How set default value of databound radiobuttonlist to nothing if null

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this databound radiobuttonlist in my gridview....

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblMyField" runat="server" 
      SelectedValue='<%# IIf(Eval("MyField") Is DBNull.Value, "0", Eval("MyField")) %>' 
       RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="flow">
 <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

If the data is null I want ***nothing*** to be selected in the rbl. How can I do this? I know I'm close. I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set a hiddenfield on each row and set the value of that to your MyField to something not 0 or 1. Then check in behind code

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hiddenField" runat="server" value='<%# if(Eval("MyField") is DBNull.Value ? 2 : 0 %>' />
```

then loop through each row and check (getting HiddenField object with FindControl)

```
if(hiddenField.Value == "2") // or whatever you want to set it to
    rblMyField.ClearSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping there would be an easier way of doing it, just in the HTML alone.